# How to change a message in a boolean variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to modify a code so when a LED turn on and off, the program will show an Active-Inactive message, instead of a classic boolean True-false.

I'm currently using this code in a Beaglebone Black, I'm new in Node.js, and I found it in a book (Exploring BeagleBone), when I ran it like it was in the book it worked showing a message of: `Led is: true, Led is: false` , but when I tried to modify it to show active-inactive, it didn't work.

```
function toggleLED()
{
    isOn = !isOn    // invert the isOn state in each call
    if (isOn) b.digitalWrite(LED3Pin, 1); // light the led
    else b.digitalWrite(LED3Pin, 0); // turn off the led
    if (isOn) isOn = 'active'; // changing default TRUE message for active
    else isOn = 'inactive'; // changing default FALSE message for inactive
    console.log('LED is: ' + isOn); // show the state
}
```

I expect the output of this code as: `LED is: active, LED is: inactive, LED is: active, LED is: inactive`, and so on, but the actual output just shows the first as `active` and the rest as `inactive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toggleLED()
{
    isOn = !isOn    // invert the isOn state in each call
    if (isOn) b.digitalWrite(LED3Pin, 1); // light the led
    else b.digitalWrite(LED3Pin, 0); // turn off the led
    console.log('LED is: ' + isOn ? 'active' : 'inactive'); // show the state
}
```

You changed variable `isOn` from boolean value `true` or `false` to string `"active"` or `"inactive"`, which would be considered as `true` the next call. That's why the rest will all be `inactive`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked, I'd like to add that I needed to make a small change in the ```console.log``` line in order to work better and it was: ```console.log('LED is: ' + (isOn ? 'active' : 'inactive'));```